# What is syntax of apache rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite a url on my machine which is runnig on 8080 port.
I need to display `http://abc.com/mebaz` instead of `http://abc:8080/designers/mebaz`
What is syntax for it?
I tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /designers/mebaz http://abc.com/mebaz
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with programming, therefore it's off-topic.

Comment: 11,000 questions tagged with mod-rewrite would disagree with you

Comment: @vivek - you're thinking the wrong way around - you are "rewriting" the request before Apache continues processing it, so your rule is backwards  -try /mebaz /designers/mebaz instead.

Comment: @PaulDixon 11.000 people jumping off the cliff does not make it right.

Comment: @David, but it has to make you wonder what's so cool about the cliff. I'm totally jumping, it must be awesome.

Comment: @PaulDixon I meant suicide. Don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/designers/mebaz$ mebaz
```